# Lack of understanding another person's lack of understanding

Tags: single-word-requests

> "Understanding a concept so well, that the concept of someone else struggling to understand this concept seems foreign."

Example:
Person A is very familiar with a how to use a smartphone. They've known how to use one for as long as they can remember.

Person B asks person A for help with their smartphone (they are not as familiar with the concept of a smartphone, or how it operates).

Person A might struggle to understand what struggles person B is presented with. They might have deep knowledge of exactly how the smartphone works, but lack the understanding of how another person might misinterpret or misunderstand the smartphone.

Is there a word for this phenomena?

On the flip side of this example, a 'person C' might learn how to use a smartphone, have the same knowledge of how it works, but also understand what aspects are tricky to grasp for beginners/new users and how to teach people to use it.

Comment: *Confused*? *Perplexed*? What form does the lack of understanding take in your view? And why does the *object* of the lack of understanding make a difference here? Not understanding why somebody else doesn't understand something should be no different than not understanding why the sky is blue. Why not just ask for a single word that describes a lack of understanding in general?

Comment: @ImNotAH: this is a great question but it's at risk of closure unless you [edit] it to include a sample sentence showing how your requested word would be used. You can hover your pointer over a tag to see the tag info; for SWRs, read here: [tag:single-word-requests]. :-)

Comment: Another possible interpretation pending clarification: "I don't understand why you can't understand what should be obvious to everyone, including me." That could be *arrogance* or *egotism*.

Comment: Is the word meant to be used in a spoken or written language, casual or formal?

Comment: Some comments are answering the question title, not the request expressed in the body. In my opinion, the Q is not about *understanding* =  tolerance/sympathy/pity but *understanding* = **knowledge/grasp/comprehend**

Comment: To person A, the knowledge in question is *like water to a fish*.

Answer (score 5):

**Curse of knowledge**

> The curse of knowledge is a cognitive bias that occurs when an individual, communicating with other individuals, unknowingly assumes that the others have the background to understand. For example, in a classroom setting, teachers have difficulty teaching novices because they cannot put themselves in the position of the student. A brilliant professor might no longer remember the difficulties that a young student encounters when learning a new subject. This curse of knowledge also explains the danger behind thinking about student learning based on what appears best to faculty members, as opposed to what has been verified with students.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge

Comment: This looks like the best candidate despite it not being a single word. I'm not entirely persuaded that native speakers would understand its meaning, if someone were to say a college professor had the curse of knowledge, I might think that he was burdened with a gift and ask why having "knowledge" was a curse. Is this expression commonly used and understood?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The 'curse of knowledge' is the _name_ of this type of cognitive bias. (Whether is it a good name is debatable, but not relevant here.) Many cognitive biases https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases have names that are not informative to laymen (or may even confuse). However, it is commonly understood in its fields (psychology, behavioral science), I'd suggest.

Comment: "Commonly-used and understood?"  I had to look it up.  Also, to my mind, it doesn't answer the question which asks simply for "a word".  You might as well say "Not a teacher"!

Answer (score 2):

**The curse of expertise** encompasses an expert's inability (at least without further training) to communicate their knowledge effectively to a non-expert.

Here is a Psychology Today article  ("[The Curse of Expertise](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/choke/201103/the-curse-expertise)" by Sian Beilock) describing the phenomenon:

> Experts are called upon to teach those less knowledgeable all the time. Teachers must predict the issues and misconceptions that students will face when learning a new and tricky concept in, say, a physics class. And, baseball coaches must understand the types of problems that a pitcher may encounter when learning to throw a new curve ball. If not, how will the coaches devise the right training techniques to help their pitcher out of trouble? *Yet, stepping outside your own point of view and relating to people who have less knowledge and skill is not such an easy task.* **People with a lot of knowledge are not as good as one might think at doing this.**

The research summarized in the article shows that experts at using phones were the least accurate at estimating how long it took new users to learn a phone:

> Sales people focused so closely on their own performance and how effortlessly they operated the phone that they had a hard time predicting novices' misconceptions and mistakes. Because of this, sales people were the least accurate predictors of the new users' learning time and failed to predict most of the trouble novices got into.

As the original researcher, [P.M. Hinds (1999)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/376d/8193541fe89acb09cb13a8d7ae035a001dec.pdf), explains, the cognitive bias is consistent with the **curse of knowledge**, which is predicated on not being able to effectively think of oneself in a less expert state. The **curse of expertise** is specific to not being able to communicate or explain that expertise.

Lots of other sources use this term to describe struggles with communicating expertise to new learners:

- "[The Science of Smart: Four Secrets To Lift The 'Curse Of Expertise,](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/article/the-science-of-smart-four-secrets-to-lift-the-curse-of-expertise/)'" NOVA, 28 Jan. 2013.
- Fisher M, Keil FC. "[The Curse of Expertise: When More Knowledge Leads to Miscalibrated Explanatory Insight](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26369299)." Cogn Sci., 40.5 (2016), 1251-69. doi: 10.1111/cogs.12280. Epub 2015 Sep 15.
- "Assume Teachers Are Victims of the Curse of Expertise and Protect Yourself," section title in Michael W. Wiederman, *[Study Less, Learn More: The Complete Guide for Busy Students](https://books.google.com/books?id=DrPIT9qLjM0C&pg=PA97&dq=%22the%20curse%20of%20expertise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-cfOm6DiAhUin-AKHXTpCx0Q6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q=%22the%20curse%20of%20expertise%22&f=false)*.

Comment: Who said anything about experts?

Comment: The original question suggests Person A has expertise compared to Person B. "Person A is **very familiar with a how to use a smartphone**. They've known how to use one for as long as they can remember." "They might have **deep knowledge** of **exactly** how the smartphone works."

Comment: I don't think I would qualify knowing how to use a smartphone well, as having expertise, if words matter to one.

Answer (score 1):

### Unempathic

The counter-example (Person C who understands person B's difficulties) is displaying **[empathy](https://www.wordnik.com/words/empathy)**

**empathy** *(n)* The ability to identify with or understand another's situation or feelings.

If I were writing your sentence, I'd simply say that your person A displays "**a lack of empathy**" toward's B. It's clear and understandable.

Personally, I've never understood the fascination with squeezing things down to one, rare and hard-to-understand word when two simple ones would get the message across much better, but if you absolutely cannot use the spacebar, you can use the form "**unempathic**", simply by adding the "removal" prefix *un-* (as in "uninterested", "unfeeling", "unmoved").

Personally I prefer the "lacking empathy" form, as there are other "un-" words formed from positive roots that carry a hint of being opposite, rather than just lacking (see "unholy", "unfriendly", "uncharitable").

A warning: although the "un-" prefix will make the meaning reasonably clear to the reader, no reputable online dictionary lists this word.

"unempathic" does show up in writing, although far less often than "empathic" (Google ngrams says there's a 100x difference, although it does have instances of "unempathic" dating back to the 1950s)

#### *is* there a different word meaning "without empathy"?

Despite it's Greeky-ness, "empathy" is actually quite a new word, and it's not Greek, [but German](https://www.etymonline.com/word/empathy).  "Empathy" entered the English language as fancy translation of a German word [ein­füh­len](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einfuehlen), which was coined by philosopher Rudolf Lotze in the 1850s from a literal translation of the Greek "en" and "pathos" (in, feelings) -- this is why the word "reverted" to "Greek" when translated into English.

**einfühlen**: to put oneself in someone's position, condition, etc.; to understand something inwardly, to empathize with it

(Lotze must have had a specific meaning in mind to create a new word, because German already had a word for this: [nachempfinden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachempfinden) )

Unfortunately, none of these three words have a single-word antonym with the sense of being *unable* to see the world from someone else's perspective.

Ironically, Greek does have a similar-sounding word to "en-pathos", but it means "hatred", which just goes to show that sometimes a word you keep using really doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: the word requested is about lack of understanding, not feeling; and, in any case, this would be too broad

Comment: Yes, but the word "Empathy" isn't about feeling, but rather understanding - the definition says this: an **understanding** of another's situation or feelings.   We have the word "sympathy" for simply sharing someone else's feelings.

Comment: ''the'' definition is imprecise if the word is understood as
_einfuehlen_; but my main reason for downvoting is that your answer is
too broad

Comment: Thanks for the reason - I can certainly accept "too broad" - the word has gained a very broad meaning (much broader than the original narrow, emotional meaning of 'einfühlen'), and lately there's a habit of people (Americans mainly) using it as a synonym for "sympathy", which it is not.  Still, the problem the OP describes *is* fundamentally one of a lack of empathy: person A is unable to relate to the experience of person B and so cannot frame his explanation in understandable terms. Person C *can* empathise with person A, and so understands that B needs even "basic" concepts explained.

Comment: perhaps it is _fundamentally_ that.  but, to put my objection in
different terms, the answer to 'what is it called when you kill a tenth
of an army' is 'decimation', not 'cruelty'.

Comment: unempathic sounds like someone lacking empathic powers. Anyway empathy is too strong here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few single words that might *suggest* this, but might not explicitly provide the meaning of someone so knowledgeable they can't understand the position of a novice. YMMV.

All definitions from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com)

> [Inure](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inure): to accusom to hardship, difficulty, pain, etc..; toughen or harden; habituation (usually followed by to)
>
> [Habituate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/habituate): To accustom (a person, the mind, etc.), as to a particular situation
>
> [Acclimate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/acclimate): To accustom or become accustomed to a new climate or environment; adapt.

Some example usages:

- Susan had become so *inured* to the vagaries of a smart phone that she could scarcely understand the difficulties Eric was having.
- *Habituated* to the reality of US politics, Susan could scarcely understand Eric's confusion.
- While *acclimated* to 80-hour workweeks, Susan could still empathize (Thanks, @KrisW) with new associates who were not so *inured* to the demanding schedule.

Answer (score 0):

You might say that person C is ***aware*** of what will help Person B and that, conversely, person A is [***unaware***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unaware), even *ignorant*, of what will help person B.

*Aware* - Informed, cognizant, conscious, sensible. To know. (OED)

Comment: A reason for the down vote would be helpful...

Comment: Not my DV but I don't think it deserves an UV because it lacks detail, and there's no link. You can find a link in any online dictionary with more or less the same terse definition, but if you're going to cite the OED then be a bit more generous.

Comment: *Same comment that I gave to Xanne's answer*: If someone were to say that a college professor was unaware, I would ask them to explain what they meant. The word could be used but it would need context.

Answer (score 0):

Unmindful, defined ny Google’s dictionary as:

> not conscious or aware. "Danielle seemed unmindful of her parents'
>   plight" synonyms: heedless of, taking no notice of, paying no heed to,
>   careless of, disregardful of, regardless of, unheeding of, neglectful
>   of, unconscious of, oblivious to, inattentive to, blind to, deaf to;
>   More

The theory of mind is the general approach to our own knowledge that other people may differ in emotions, knowledge, etc.  At what point one’s own knowledge makes it harder to perceive others varies, but many experts like teaching introductory courses and are very good at it.

Comment: If someone were to say that a college professor was unmindful, I would ask them to explain what they meant. The word could be used but it would need context.

Answer (score -1):

unsympathetic

And it does not need to be about smartphones or anything like that.

Not understanding someone else's struggle(s), means you are an unsympathetic person.

Merriam Webster's definitions:

Definition of unsympathetic
: not given to, marked by, or arising from sympathy : not sympathetic
an unsympathetic bystander
an unsympathetic review

Sympathetic:

3 : given to, marked by, or arising from sympathy, compassion, friendliness, and sensitivity to others' emotions
a sympathetic gesture

That said, there is no word for being unsympathetic about someone's lack of understanding.

So,  you add a word: unsympathetic to lack of understanding by another

Comment: +1 for “there is no word for being unsympathetic about someone's lack of understanding” I think you're right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  It occured to me post facto that given the screen name, the question seems to describe the horrible historical personage. Also, for the record, lack of understanding is ambiguous. Could be emotional could be intellectual. There are some mathematical permutations of it, taking into account two meanings for each person. Not sure if that is 12 or fewer...

Comment: Oh, come now. The topic is far removed from the dictator, the question talks about smart phones not abject cruelty but I see a number of upvoted answers have been downvoted. Why?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is it by chance that some who says he is not Hitler is asking questions about understanding and lack thereof? The smartphone is the object that provides agency, it could be anything.

Comment: Yes. It's pure coincidence, the user chose an infelicitous username but their question is quite unrelated to  the WWII dictator.

Comment: @Mari-LouA How can one be so sure? People's unconscious betray them all the time.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps a metonymy for lack of understanding another person's lack of understanding might be parent or (not to play favorites) child.